# connecting xml file to the xtratreelist control

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, devexpress

how to connect the xml data file to the xtraTreeList control by using C#.net?

Comment: i'll , but if answer fulfills my questions requirement.

Comment: you should also [care more about formulating your questions](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XtraTreeList can load data only from xml, which was created using the treeList's ExportToXml method.  In this case, the TreeList's TreeList.ImportFromXml method will load data from an xml file.  To learn about this alternative, please refer to the Export and Import Data topic.

An alternative to this task is to bind the XtraTreeList to a DataSet, which is filled using the DataSet's ReadXml method.